# How to determine reason for failure with AFNetworking AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, afnetworking

I've inherited a project and am implementing AFNetworking and reading the docs it sounds great and much simpler than the current code. I have a url with json data so I'm doing the following, but getting the failure block and no idea why. I'm sure it's there, but how can I dig into AF and log the responses to determine failure reason. I know the url works, but perhaps its hitting the url but having trouble parsing?

```
NSString *listURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:GET_LIST,BASE_URL];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:briefListURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                                                            self.list = [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)JSON];                                                                                                    
                                                                                        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                                                            [self listOperationDidFail];
                                                                                        }];
```

Comment: `failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}`

Comment: wow thanks so much for the quick response! that was easy, i got this: 

Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/plain" UserInfo=0x8454e80 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=[{"newsletters":.....then the dump of the content

im not a networking expert, but the docs i have internally say this url spits out json, i guess it just isnt? can afnetworking handle this?

Comment: found info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547405/i-found-error-with-afnetworking-for-json-parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Larme this worked:

```
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }
```

also, to answer my own issue above with text/plain. just add this before setting up operation:

```
  [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];
```